# $pV$ diagram of pure substance

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

Why does the specific volume of saturated solid state of water decreases with increasing pressure and the specific volume of saturated liquid wrt vaporisation increases with pressure? Can anyone explain this intuitively?

Comment: Intuition is a fairly personal thing. Yours might not be anything like mine. What, specifically confuses you?

Answer (score 0):

The specific volume of a saturated liquid also decreases with pressure (at constant temperature) as you move into the sub cooled liquid zone. However, along the saturation line, you are also increasing temperature, and the thermal expansion effect wins out over the compressibility.